# Copy file from a website to sharePoint c#

Tags: sharepoint-server, development

I am trying to copy a file from a website to a SharePoint but each time an exception appear:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in UploadFileToSharePoint.exe
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

```
  CopyDocuments("http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf", "https://sites.inside-share.name.com/sites/000000", "Documents");
    

    public void CopyDocuments(string srcUrl, string destUrl, string destLibrary)
    {
        ClientContext srcContext = new ClientContext(srcUrl);

        ClientContext destContext = new ClientContext(destUrl);

        Web srcWeb = srcContext.Web;

        List srcList = srcWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

        Web destWeb = destContext.Web;

        destContext.Load(destWeb);

        destContext.ExecuteQuery();
        try
        {
            //"/sites/068295/test.pdf"
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = srcContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf");
            srcContext.Load(file);
            srcContext.ExecuteQuery();
            string location = destWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + destLibrary.Replace(" ", "") + "/" + file.Name;
            FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(srcContext, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(destContext, location, fileInfo.Stream, true);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = srcContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf");` this lines implies that the source file is also in SharePoint, which is it not. You need to to a WebRequest or similar to fetch the file from the website before uploading it to SP

Answer (score 0):

Your code is assuming that the source location (http://www.africau.edu/) is a SharePoint environment, which I feel not. Please follow Robert's suggestion to download the file first before uploading to destination.

I have tried to compile the following code to help you. It might need some small modification. Let me know if it works.

```
using System.Net;

    public void CopyDocuments(string srcUrl, string destUrl, string destLibrary)
    {
        string downloadedFilePath = @"C:\path\sample.pdf";

        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFile(srcUrl, downloadedFilePath);
            }

            //TODO: Check if downloaded file is present at downloadedFilePath

            ClientContext destContext = new ClientContext(destUrl);

            Web destWeb = destContext.Web;

            destContext.Load(destWeb);

            destContext.ExecuteQuery();

            string location = destWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') 
                + "/" 
                + destLibrary.Replace(" ", "") 
                + "/" 
                + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(downloadedFilePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(destContext, location, fs, true);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```